# Turtle Gradient Color (review code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use Turtle to print 30 hexagons that are spiralling and have a gradient color change from red to black.

I am multiplying my `for` loop `i` in order to change the set values in (r, b, g) so, at some point, it will exceed r=255. I include an `if` statement to have it not exceed this, but it's giving me the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-35d45ac44fdd>", line 20
    if r > '255'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is causing this error?

FYI I am using Anaconda and a Jupyter notebook.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle 

def draw_hexagon (t, size):
    n=6
    angle= 360/n
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(angle)

turtle.colormode(255)
mega=turtle.Turtle()
mega.speed(1000) 
leng = 100
for i in range(30):
    r = 5+(i*10)
    g = 0
    b = 0
    color = (r, b, g)
    if r > 255
       print color(r,b,g)
   mega.fillcolor(color) 
   mega.begin_fill()
   draw_hexagon(mega, leng)
   mega.end_fill()
   leng = leng + 5
   mega.left(5)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You're missing a `:`, and if this is Python 3, you're missing `()` with `print`

Comment: Oh yes! Good point, thanks! However, now I am running it and it is saying:

Comment: TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (265, 0, 0)

Comment: Isn't this what I am trying to prevent from happening with my if statement? I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Yes, that's what you're trying to prevent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Added clarification belongs in your posting (edit the original), not in comments.  Also, fix your indentation.  Finally, give us the *full* error message, not just the one-line text.  Include the trace-back

Comment: You have your test backward: if **r > 255**, you *know* the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to not use the `if` statement to get around the error but rather fix your math to avoid it in the first place.  Plus some code cleanup:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

MIN_COLOR = 5
MAX_COLOR = 255

COUNT = 30
ANGLE = 5

STARTING_LENGTH = 100
LENGTH_INCREMENT = 5

N = 6

def draw_polygon(turtle, size):
    angle = 360 / N
    for _ in range(N):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(angle)

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

mega = Turtle()
mega.speed('fastest')

length = STARTING_LENGTH

for r in range(COUNT):

    red = round(r * ((MAX_COLOR - MIN_COLOR) / (COUNT - 1))) + MIN_COLOR

    color = (red, 0, 0)

    mega.fillcolor(color)
    mega.begin_fill()
    draw_polygon(mega, length)
    mega.end_fill()

    length += LENGTH_INCREMENT
    mega.left(ANGLE)

mega.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```